# How to listen to headphone/headset button events in Javascript/Node/Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I've tried listening to the `mediaSession` events, but this only seems to work for the media keys on my keyboard. How can I listen to the events from the buttons on a headset in Javascript, Node or Electron?

```
      navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', () => { 
        console.log('play')
      });
      navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', () => { 
        console.log('pause');
      });
      navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', () => { 
        console.log('previoustrack')
      });
      navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('nexttrack', () => { 
        console.log('nexttrack')
      });
      navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('stop', () => { 
        console.log('stop')
      });
      navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('hangup', () => { 
        console.log('hangup')
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `The navigator.mediaSession` API you're using is designed to handle media controls on a user's keyboard.
In order to do that you need to use something like Web Bluetooth API or Node-HID here is a good resource to read about Node-HID https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid, and a good resource for Web Bluethooth API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API